# Extract database users with passwords

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I want to script out the database users in my contained database using sql login. I am using the below query but it is only creating a database user and not a sql login with password. Is it possible to script out the password in a encrypted output so I can restore it properly?

```
SELECT '-- [-- DB USERS --] --' AS [-- SQL STATEMENTS --], 3 AS [-- RESULT ORDER HOLDER --] 
UNION SELECT  'IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT [name] FROM sys.database_principals WHERE [name] = ' + SPACE(1) + '''' + [name] + '''' + ') 
BEGIN CREATE USER ' + SPACE(1) + QUOTENAME([name]) + ' FOR LOGIN ' + QUOTENAME([name]) + ' WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = ' + QUOTENAME([default_schema_name]) + SPACE(1) + 'END; ' AS [-- SQL STATEMENTS --], 4 AS [-- RESULT ORDER HOLDER --] FROM sys.database_principals AS rm
WHERE [type] IN ('U', 'S', 'G') -- windows users, sql users, windows groups
```

result

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT [name] FROM sys.database_principals WHERE [name] ='DJlogin') BEGIN CREATE USER  [DJlogin] FOR LOGIN [DJlogin] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = [dbo] END;
```

Comment: 99% sure you cannot query a user's password.

Comment: Im thinking of extracting it in a encrypted password and we can restore it to another VM.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to script out the database users in my contained database using
>   sql login

The central idea of contained databases that they are **transportable**, so database principals (or users) of such databases are not mapped to instance level logins because they are independent and their scope a "contained database".

Therefore, such users can be moved to another instance/server together with a database by a simple backup/restore or attach/detach of such database. Of course, the new instance should have enabled support of such databases.

In case if a database principal is really connected to an instance level login, such login can be scripted via famous: [How to transfer logins and passwords between instances of SQL Server](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/918992/how-to-transfer-logins-and-passwords-between-instances-of-sql-server)